# Making A Complex Clock And It Doesnt Display In My Document Did i Do something wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

So im making a clock that takes the 24 hour time and converts it to 12 hour and determines am and pm but even tho the html document has the script linked and the element with the id for it to change it doesnt display on the document

Heres The HTML and the javascript:

```js
function mainClock() {
 var clock = new Date();
 var h = clock.getHours();
 var m = clock.getMinutes();
 var s = clock.getSeconds();
 var tz = 'str';
 if (h > 12) {
  h = h - 12;
  tz = 'PM';
  return h;
  return tz;
 } else {
  tz = 'AM';
  return tz;
 }

 m = checkTime(m);
 s = checkTime(s);
 document.getElementsById('clock').innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s + tz;
 setTimeout(mainClock, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
 if (i < 10) {
  i = '0' + i;
 }
 return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="mainClock()">
    <span id="clock"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance and [image: heres a picture of the faulty element]

Comment: It's not the problem here, but you should be setting [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the DOM node, not [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). `.textContent` avoids problems when you accidentally have HTML syntax in your text.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your snippet by changing the following things:
Remove `return h;` and `return tz` in your if/else statements.

Change `document.getElementsByClassName('clock').innerHTML` to `document.querySelector('#clock').innerHTML`

```js
function mainClock() {
 var clock = new Date();
 var h = clock.getHours();
 var m = clock.getMinutes();
 var s = clock.getSeconds();
 var tz = 'str';
 if (h > 12) {
  h = h - 12;
  tz = 'PM';
 } else {
  tz = 'AM';
 }

 m = checkTime(m);
 s = checkTime(s);
 document.querySelector('#clock').innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s + tz;
 setTimeout(mainClock, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
 if (i < 10) {
  i = '0' + i;
 }
 return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="resources/js/script.js"></script>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="mainClock()">
    <span id="clock"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP still has questions so I posted a complete, working example. Not sure what your passive aggressiveness is about @DiabolicWords

Comment: again i didnt mean to use the elements by classname let me change the snippet to how it is now

Comment: see look if you change it to getelementbyid it doesnt work and this is what im asking

Answer (score 0):

My [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51449974/3029173) answer shows how to fix your existing code. I wanted to show a simpler way of writing your logic, for comparison's sake:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const now = new Date();
  const formattedTime = now.toLocaleTimeString('en-US');
  document.querySelector('#clock').innerHTML = formattedTime;
}, 500);
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: It uses setInterval to execute a function every 500ms. Each time the function executes, it grabs the current date and sets the innerHTML to the date. If you have more specific questions, I'd look up setInterval and Date.toLocalTimeString

Comment: also why do you have to use query selector why wont getelementbyid work